# Set cookie to only show DIV once per session

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I have a DIV which is displayed on page load.
It can be closed via a button or by clicking anywhere in the window (as per a regular modal).

I need this DIV to only be shown once per session. At the moment it is shown every time a new page loads on the site. Is there an easy solution?

I'd like to continue using JQuery show/hide to do this as per my working version below.  Any help greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="promoModal" class="promomodal">
  <div class="promo-modal-content">
    <span class="promo-close">&times;</span>
    CONTENT
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
  .promomodal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .promo-modal-content {
    background-color: #071177;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .promo-close {
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

</style>
```

JS

```
var modal = document.getElementById("promoModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("promo-close")[0];

  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.promomodal').show();

    span.onclick = function () {
      jQuery('.promomodal').hide();
    }
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        jQuery('.promomodal').hide();
      }
    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Is it okay to define someone as "leaving" the site as someone who hasn't loaded a page in x minutes? e.g. if they haven't visited the site in 5 minutes, they've left it?

Comment: If a cookie not already exists, show the div and create/store the cookie. The cookie should not have an expiration date so it will automagically be deleted when user closes the browser. This way the div will open only once per session, not on every page.

Comment: @TobyMellor I would prefer it just only shows on one page per visit. At the moment, it loads on every single page on the site, every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var modal = document.getElementById("promoModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("promo-close")[0];

  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   if (sessionStorage.getItem('promomodalWasShown') == null) {
      $('.promomodal').show();
      sessionStorage.setItem('promomodalWasShown', 'true');
   }

    span.onclick = function () {
      jQuery('.promomodal').hide();
    }
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        jQuery('.promomodal').hide();
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I have implemented this solution but it seems to have no effect. The modal still shows on every page of the site, every time it loads. Any thoughts why this may be happening?

Comment: Please try $(".promomodal").show( "slow", function() {
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('promomodalWasShown'));
  }); just to see what is wrong.

Comment: where do i place that?

Comment: Looks like on the first page load, the console prints 'null'. Is that expected? The problem is, on every other page of the site, the modal still loads, and the console log no longer prints null.

Comment: It is shown on each page just because it is normal div shown by default. And with show() it is shown second time. Please set display: none; for .promomodal in your css.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks so much for your help.